# THREE is not defined; how do I fix this?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am currently experimenting with Three.js but I can't seem to fix this error, I've tried and searched for a lot of answers but I cant fix it.

I've included the threejs library
and in my script everything is written just fine

This is my html index file

```html
<body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r79/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/242637/TrackballProjectorDetector.js"></script>
    <script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/242637/AsciiEffect.js"></script>

</body>
```

This is some part of the script file

```js
function init() {
      var width = window.innerWidth || 2;
      var height = window.innerHeight || 2;
      container = document.createElement('div');
      document.body.appendChild(container);
      var info = document.createElement('div');
      info.style.position = 'absolute';
      info.style.top = '20px';
      info.style.width = '100%';
      info.style.textAlign = 'center';
      info.innerHTML = 'Drag to change the view';
      container.appendChild(info);
      camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, width / height, 1, 1000);
      camera.position.y = 150;
      camera.position.z = 500;
      controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera);
      scene = new THREE.Scene();
      var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
      light.position.set(500, 500, 500);
      scene.add(light);
      var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.25);
      light.position.set(-500, -500, -500);
      scene.add(light);
      sphere = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(200, 20, 10), new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial());
      scene.add(sphere);
```

I get an error on the line:

```js
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, width / height, 1, 1000);
```

But when I remove it, the error goes down to the next `THREE` element.

Comment: My guess is that you're executing `script.js` before you load `three.min.js`. Change the order of your `<script>` tags so all dependencies are loaded first, then put your code after. Also, I recommend you use [a newer version of Three.js](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/three.js), since `r79` is about 3-4 years old.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r79/three.min.js"></script>
```

I'd say the order may be important here. If the `init` function is run when loading `script.js`<sup>(a)</sup>, `THREE` will not yet have been defined, since that would happen on the *following* line.

The solution, in that case, would be to load `three.js` *before* your script file.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> This is often done at the end of a `js` file but we can't be sure in this case, since we don't have the entire file. Hence I'd be looking at that file to see if it's something like:

```js
function init() {
      blahBlahBlah();
}

init();
```